# Azure ADB2C using custom policy Trying to force user to login everytime

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to force user to login every time. Came across this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-manage-sso-and-token-configuration

When I tried Scope with Application, Tenant, Policy options I was able to upload my policy. Disabled option giving Schema Error

```
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
   <SingleSignOn Scope="Disabled" />
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

The 'Scope' attribute is invalid - The value 'Disabled' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06:UserJourneyBehaviorScopeType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.

Unfortunately the schemas validation link is also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be set to `Suppressed`, not `Disabled`, see [the XML schema for Trust Policy Framework](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/d740d68f2f5433883e75f5bc662b661f553d836a/B2CPolicies/Advanced%20Policies%20Starter%20pack/TrustFrameworkPolicy_0.3.0.0.xsd#L1996) for more information.